# How do people scans on iOS and MacOS interact?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos.app

With iCloud Photo Library we now have synced people albums. How do the scans on different devices interact?

I recently got a new phone which initiated a new scan and messed up my carefully sorted and trained people album by merging several groups of people. In the end the situation was that bad that I had pictures with twice the same person on it. It seems that on certain pictures with 2 people, the phone sorted the first person as Alice and the MacBook sorted the second person as Alice and then they got merged and there were two Alices on one picture.

I reset all people data which initiated new scans on both iOS and macOS and I just started naming people and there are unwanted merges again.

Comment: Which versions of iOS and macOS are you using? This is important as the synchronisation of faces is vastly improved on iOS 11 and High Sierra.

Comment: Everything the latest released version, no beta. So at the moment iOS 11.1.2 and macOS 10.13.1

Comment: Also, there was no synchronization of face data before iOS 11 and high Sierra... I guess that can be called vastly improved :)

Comment: Well, there was a well-known work-around for iOS 11 and pre-High Sierra where you could sync the recognized persons using smart albums. I wanted to be sure you were not talking about this.